# Why does IL2CPP run with no error and no output

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

My unity version is 5.3.4f, and I hava C# script as a.cs and compiled a.exe and it runs OK. Then I use IL2CPP to translate a.exe into C++ compiled exe a_il2cpp.exe with command:

> il2cpp.exe --outputpath=a_il2cpp.exe --cachedirectory="obj_cache" generatedcppdir="generated_cpp" a.exe

But it shows no error and no output, do I miss something? I have C++ compiler installed.

Comment: no error and no output usually means success in unix systems; did you check the exit code? you can do this by writing `echo $?` after your command

Answer (score 1):

Unity does not support using IL2CPP as a general mechanism for translating C# assemblies to native binaries. In theory this is possible (indeed some of the internal testing tools at Unity do this), but I don't think the command line you mention here will allow it to work.